# NoClassDefFoundError on a class within a WAR on WebLogic server

Tags: java, weblogic, war, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to deploy a WAR file on weblogic server.
This is a simple java application.
I am new to this and experimenting.

JRE: 1.5.0_41, OS: redhat 5.8, Weblogic: WebLogic Server 10.0 MP2

The contents just include a jsp file and a java file (jsp inside jsp folder and java class inside WEB-INF\classes folder and correct package structure). I am using this java util file inside the jsp for some common utility methods.

However, when I deploy the WAR, it gives me NoClassDefinitionFoundError for this java utility class.

I have searched the threads and found that this exception points to some other inherent issue in the deployment. It also mentioned class path conflicts etc. I can understand this issue when it comes to using a class from an external JAR file, but could not understand how it fails to locate a file in the same context as that of the jsp.

How come the import statements in the jsp worked and the jsp got compiled and rendered and failed only when the part of accessing this object came into picture? (runtime problem maybe?)

Please educate me on this. My debugging efforts are still on. Thanks a lot, folks!!

[P.S.: Could it be because i compiled and built my source using eclipse setting 1.7 compliance and used it on a lesser JRE?]

Comment: please post entire stack trace.

Comment: Also make sure that the full package path live under web-inf/classes... like `WEB-INF/classes/your/package/name/myclass.class`

Answer (score 0):

For a war file classes is normally packaged inside WEB-INF/classes, not classes.

Comment: Yes, sorry, its already like that. I missed to mention it. Will edit my post. Thanks.